# How can I build a hashed region for null column values in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

With `data: [null, null, 10, 20, 20, 33, 23, 23, 22, 5]`

How can i build a hashed region in Highcharts, like displayed to the left of the blue columns, the hashed region would represent a group of null data points?

I had thought to overlay 2 chart types to solve this. Wondering if anyone has a better idea here? Maybe using Renderer or an area line chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Plot bands](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines)

In chart option add following

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82w4dpt7/)

```
events: {
 load: function () {
 var series_data=this.series[0].data;//this is series data
 for(var i=0;i<series_data.length;i++){
      if(series_data[i].y==null){//find null value in series
         //adds plot band
          this.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({  
              from: i-1, //point back
              to: i+1,   //point after
              color: '#c5d8f7',//this color represent null value region
          });
      }
  }

}
}
```